# как сделать чтобы функция возвращала сумму уже полученных четных чисел из списка

Tags: python

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]#список
def p_even(lst):
   even = [x for x in lst if x % 2==0]#отбор четных чисел
   res = sum(even)#здесь уже ошибка

   print(res)
   return res
    
p_even(lst)
```

Comment: even=[2,4,6,8] res=20 в чём там ошибка ?

Comment: ¿Зачем создавать список только для того, чтобы посчитать сумму его элементов?

Comment: да, сейчас проверил, в любом другом компиляторе дает верный ответ

Comment: но в гуглколаб выдает это 'int' object is not callable

Comment: тебе серьезно с таким ретингом интересен ответ на свой вопрос?

Comment: я не сомневался, что в колабе работает, но проверил - всё работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет ошибки, проверил в PyCharm, выдает 20, как и должно быть.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: Чем отличаются русскоязычные форумы от англоязычных: на русскоязычных мало кто даст конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос, но обязательно затроллят автора вопроса, ответят по делу 5%... У вас есть время писать комментарии к моему посту, но ответить на вопрос автора желающих не нашлось.